# jQuery: Updating an option's text inside a select after the option has already been added?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I've searched all around for a solution and have found nothing. Here is some sample code:

```
$('#myselect').append(
   '<option id=\'myoption\'></option>'
  );
$('#mytextfield').change(function() {
 $('#myoption').html($(this).val);
});
```

so, i want to change the select option's html whenever my text field is changed. any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the missing `()` on `val`, writing `innerHTML` of an `<option>` is generally unreliable due to how browsers implement form fields, and writing the `innerHTML` of *anything* from user input is highly inadvisable—what if the user typed something with `<` or `&` symbols in?

Use the standard DOM `text` property to change the label text instead, eg.:

```
var myoption= new Option();
$('#myselect').append(myoption);
$('#mytextfield').change(function() {
    myoption.text= this.value;
});
```

(or `$(this).val()` if you must, but I think the plain-DOM version is more readable.)

Answer (score 3):

val is a function.  I'm not sure if this is the reason for youyr problem as you didn't say what result or error you are getting...

Comment: there were a few problems, but it was really because i was adding the event to the wrong element. sorry for the poor wording. +1 =)